# Is there a faster way to get correlation coefficents?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, correlation

I have two large datasets A (100,000x10,000) and B (100,000x250) and I want to calculate the Pearson correlation between those.

The `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` function with `metric='correlation'` does exactly what I want.

```
corr = 1 - cdist(A.T,B.T,'correlation')
```

But it takes about 5 times as long as `numpy.corrcoef` although I can discard most parts of it where correlation is calculated within one of the datasets.

```
corr = corrcoef(np.hstack((A,B)).T)[len(A.T):,:len(A.t)].T
```

Is there a better way to do this fast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this implementation, I don't have enough memory to test with your input size.

It looks like internally the function implements uses python loops [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/b5d8bab88af61d61de09641243848df63380a67f/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L2607).

```
def pairwise_correlation(A, B):
    am = A - np.mean(A, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    bm = B - np.mean(B, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    return am.T @ bm /  (np.sqrt(
        np.sum(am**2, axis=0,
               keepdims=True)).T * np.sqrt(
        np.sum(bm**2, axis=0, keepdims=True)))
```

Comment: Your implementation is about 30 times faster than scipy cdist and 5 times faster than numpy corrcoef.

Comment: Do you have an implementation which works with scipy.sparse arrays? This one raises an error with sparse arrays.

Comment: Will require some refactoring, I think that it makes a question on its own merit.